# jquery : Text on moving div (infinite wall)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to make an infinite wall which will pull text from database and show it on the wall. I have written this code -

```
$(function() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 100.0;
    var z=0;
    setInterval(function() {
        x -= 0.1;
        y -= 0.1;
        z++;
        if (x <= -100.0){ 
            $("#h1d1").html("loop div 1 :" + z);
            x = 0;
        }
        if (y <= 0){
            $("#h1d2").html("loop div 2 :" + z);
            y = 100.0;
        }
        $('#movimg1').css('left', x + "%");
        $('#movimg2').css('left', y + "%");

    }, 10);
    $("#stopbutton").click(function() {
        $('#movimg1').stop();
    });
})
```

But the text are not behaving as I wanted it to behave. It changes in the middle of the screen which I don't want. I need the text to change when it is out of view.
https://jsfiddle.net/oa0wdxcx/2/

A couple more things- I want to add a play/pause button. Any advice on how I could achieve that would be much appreciated. Also I want the divs to be inside #wrap div, but if I change the position attribute to relative, the divs don't remain together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What text? I don't see any on the wall.

Comment: Looks right to me? https://jsfiddle.net/oa0wdxcx/1/

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update. https://jsfiddle.net/oa0wdxcx/2/ latest fiddle here

Comment: It changes because this code: `$("#h1d1").html("loop div 1 :" + z);` and `$("#h1d2").html("loop div 2 :" + w);`.. Whats strange about it?

Comment: Be specific about your requirements.....

Comment: "It changes in the middle of the screen which I don't want." - I meant I want the text to change when it is out of view/scope.

Comment: @Shawon0418 I updated my answer with start/stop buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the conditions.

```
            if (x <= -100.0) {
                z++;
                $("#h1d1").html("loop div 1 :" + z);
                x = 100; /* change this line */ 

            }
            if (y <= -100.0) { /* change this line */ 
                w++;
                $("#h1d2").html("loop div 2 :" + w);
                y = 100;

            }
```

the conditions says that if any of these two divs reaches `left:-100%` then the element must place at the end of queue at `left:100%`.

And one other thing you can combine these if statements and only use `x` to do the transition.

For start and stop button to work, you should kill the simulation to stop by using `clearInterval()` function, and call `doSimulate()` to start again:

```
        var started = true;

        $("#stopbutton").click(function () {
                if(started) {
                    clearInterval(sim);
                    $(this).html('Start');
                    started = false;
                }else{
                    doSimulate();
                    $(this).html('Stop');
                    started = true;
                }
            });
```

Here is jsFiddle [With Start/Stop Working.](https://jsfiddle.net/oa0wdxcx/7/)

Comment: Thanks, the text is exactly how I needed it. But theres a blinking line after the end of second div each time. How can I solve it?

Comment: I've updated the code for start and stop. I don't see any blinking line!

Comment: If you see a blinking line please show me where it is, because I can't find it yet.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/97za8q. Can it be a browser issue? I'm seeing this on both chrome and firefox. I solved it here https://jsfiddle.net/oa0wdxcx/9/, but I'm not sure if it is the proper way.

Comment: Yes now I see, it's because you use background image a I didn't. It occurs because animation's loop plays the first frame twice; when the second div is out of scope and then should be placed at the end. and you fixed it by skipping the first frame.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/oa0wdxcx/6/) JSFiddle, i added one more to get a smooth transition back to start.. The third should contain same message as first.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div id="wrap" class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="movimg message1" id="movimg1">
                 <h1 class="header">start div 1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="movimg message2" id="movimg2">
                 <h1 class="header">start div 2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="movimg message1" id="movimg3">
                 <h1 class="header">start div 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button class="button" id="startbutton" style="display:none;">Start</button>
        <button class="button" id="stopbutton">Stop</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    var x = 200.0;
    var interval;

    function start(){
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            x -= 0.1;
            if (x <= 0.0) {
                x = 200;
            }
            $('#movimg1').css('left', (x-200) + "%");
            $('#movimg2').css('left', (x-100) + "%");
            $('#movimg3').css('left', x + "%");
        }, 10);
    }

    start();

    $("#stopbutton").click(function () {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
        $(this).hide();
        $("#startbutton").show();
    });

    $("#startbutton").click(function () {
        start();
        $(this).hide();
        $("#stopbutton").show();
    });
})
```

CSS

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap {
    width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
}
.movimg{
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/89/ed/e5/89ede56bcc8243787e55676ab28f287f.jpg');
}
#movimg1 {
    left: 0%;
}
#movimg2 {
    left: 100%;
}
#movimg3 {
    left: 200%;
}
.header {
    text-align: center;
}
.button{
    top: 600px;
    position: relative;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Now with Stop and Start buttons: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/oa0wdxcx/6/)